# Не могу скачать файл что делать? Google Drive Android

Tags: java, android, google-drive

```
GoogleApiClient client;
GoogleSignInOptions gso;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this, this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();

    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(client);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, 1);
}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}

@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode==1){
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();

            DriveId driveId=DriveId.decodeFromString("1CeC6OqnuPexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
            DriveFile driveFile= driveId.asDriveFile();

            DriveApi.DriveContentsResult connectionResult=driveFile.open(client,DriveFile.MODE_READ_ONLY,null).await();

            if (connectionResult.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader=new InputStreamReader(connectionResult.getDriveContents().getInputStream());
                try {
                    Log.e("MainActivity=onCreate", String.valueOf(inputStreamReader.read()));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(client);
}
```

Выдает ошибку

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid DriveId: 1CeC6OqnuPexxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Не мучайтесь вы так, возьмите либу, где все это уже реализовано - [Driven](https://github.com/bingzer/Driven):

```
StorageProvider provider = new GoogleDrive();
provider.authenticate(credentials);

RemoteFile remoteFile=provider.get("blah-blah-file.txt");
remoteFile.download(new LocalFile(new File("mylocalfile.txt"));
```

P.S. Пытался вчера ответить на другой вопрос, но его уже снесли ретивые коллеги :)

Comment: Спасибо тебе добрейший человек. )))

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, credentials что это и как его создать, в моем коде его нет. Из за нее приложение не компилируется

Comment: @AndroLord просто скажите мне, что вы пошутили... Надеюсь уж такие проблемы я вам не должен помогать решать :) Я просто намечаю путь решения, а решения вы находите сами.

Comment: В гугле нет - это сильно. А голову включать не пробовали? [Credential](https://github.com/bingzer/Driven/blob/master/Library/src/main/java/com/bingzer/android/driven/Credential.java)

Comment: ` Caused by: com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException: NeedPermission`

использую authenticateAsync.